# Convert Youtube embed videoid with php preg_replace and str_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I am using this code to convert an embed youtube iframe tag to lite-youtube tag.

```
 $compa = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/embed/","",$compatibilita);
    
       $compafinal = preg_replace('/<iframe\s+.*?\s+src=(".*?").*?<\/iframe>/', '<lite-youtube
        videoid=$1
        params="controls=1&modestbranding=2&rel=0&enablejsapi=1">
        </lite-youtube>', $compa);
       echo $compafinal;
```

My problem is that Youtube src can contain for example

```
youtube.com/embed/nvcMQ234HCG8?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=https
```

and I would like to get only videoid, stripping ?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=https

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the url has query params and, if so, use just the portion before that:

```
if(strpos($compatibilita, "?") !== FALSE) { 
//Have to check if it's different to false because strpos can return 0 and 0 is falsy
  $compatibilita = substr($compatibilita, 0, strpos($compatibilita, "?"));
}

$compa = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/embed/","",$compatibilita);
    
       $compafinal = preg_replace('/<iframe\s+.*?\s+src=(".*?").*?<\/iframe>/', '<lite-youtube
        videoid=$1
        params="controls=1&modestbranding=2&rel=0&enablejsapi=1">
        </lite-youtube>', $compa);
       echo $compafinal;
```

if the url is `youtube.com/embed/nvcMQ234HCG8?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=https` the variable will be `youtube.com/embed/nvcMQ234HCG8`